# Wrong "Default From" value in Rails Mailer leads to SMTP error on Heroku with SendGrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sendgrid

I'm setting up Mail with Heroku and SendGrid and run into the following error trying to send out an email with Rails:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Cannot receive from specified address <my-email@domain.com>: Unauthenticated senders not allowed
2013-06-01T10:52:34.767516+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/api/v1/post_controller.rb:84:in `reply'
```

This domain "my-email@domain.com" comes from the "default from" field in my Mailer:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "my-email@domain.com"

  def post_notification_email(params)
    # Send mail here
  end
end
```

My big problem is that I don't know what exactly to fill in here. Is this supposed to be my email address? Does it have to be my domain? Is it my Heroku email? My SendGrid email? No idea whatsoever what to do to make SendGrid happy. Removing this line and hoping something would be filled in that works also led to errors. I'm stuck. What are others using for their "default from"?

One more piece, in case it's important: this is all still in development, so I haven't connected it to a domain. I also haven't really created a SendGrid account, just added the SendGrid add-on to my app on Heroku.

UPDATE: posting my action mailer configuration for Production:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '25',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'domain.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: There's not an issue with the from address.  That error message means that SendGrid is rejecting your credentials or auth method.  Can you post your ActionMailer configuration for production?

Comment: Just posted my mailer configuration into the question. I'm still puzzled by all this and I'm not sure where the problem is. The above seems to look good to me and credentials seem to be filled in automatically.

Comment: If you run `heroku config` do you see your SendGrid username and password in that list?  My guess is that your credentials aren't properly configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your action_mailer configured properly, (*config/production.rb*):

```
  # Sendgrid
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 25,
    domain: "example.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

Don't forget to change the **domain** parameter!
Add sendgrid to your heroku app, as following (in your terminal):

```
heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter
```

Commit changes and deploy your application to heroku. You should be able to send emails from domain you previously defined.

Comment: I added SendGrid already and it's all deployed to Heroku. I hadn't changed the "domain" parameter before and though Duh, that's it, but I'm still getting the same problem. Which domain am I supposed to fill in here? The domain of my own website? Or "*.herokuapp.com"? Or what is it?

Comment: Define your heroku domain: "your-app.herokuapp.com"

Comment: Sorry @dpaluy, I just realized I never replied to this one. I started over again following the documentation and what you described and voila, I got it to work. The bad news is that I'm still not sure what the actual problem was. But thanks a lot definitely for pointing me in the right directions on what to check and pay attention to!